# Flutter run use incorrect apk path

Tags: flutter

i used "flutter run" command to run an application。but failed with an apk not found error:

Built android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk.
"android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk" does not exist.

exactly my apk location is "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk". there is a "debug" in the middle.

so how can i config "flutter run" to use the correct path?

Comment: try `flutter run --release`

Comment: try `flutter clean` and then `flutter run`